# How to get a reliable unicode character count in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, utf-16, utf-32

Google App Engine uses Python 2.5.2, apparently with UCS4 enabled. But the GAE datastore uses UTF-8 internally. So if you store u'\ud834\udd0c' (length 2) to the datastore, when you retrieve it, you get '\U0001d10c' (length 1). I'm trying to count of the number of unicode characters in the string in a way that gives the same result before and after storing it. So I'm trying to normalize the string (from u'\ud834\udd0c' to '\U0001d10c') as soon as I receive it, before calculating its length and putting it in the datastore. I know I can just encode it to UTF-8 and then decode again, but is there a more straightforward/efficient way?

Comment: Don't try to store `u'\ud834\udd0c'`. Surrogates are not valid unicode code points, so you shouldn't rely on them being preserved in strings, or length working properly.

Comment: To clarify: `u'blah'` in Python conceptually represents a sequence of Unicode code points. So you shouldn't put UTF-16's binary representation into them.

Comment: If you deleted the sentance about encoding and decoding from your question, and added it as an answer, I'd probably upvote it, because I think it's the most *correct* thing to do to get what you're asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know I can just encode it to UTF-8 and then decode again

Yes, that's the usual idiom to fix up the problem when you have “UTF-16 surrogates in UCS-4 string” input. But as Mechanical snail said, this input *is* malformed and you should be fixing whatever produced it in preference.

> is there a more straightforward/efficient way?

Well... you *could* do it manually with a regex, like:

```
re.sub(
    u'([\uD800-\uDBFF])([\uDC00-\uDFFF])',
    lambda m: unichr((ord(m.group(1))-0xD800<<10)+ord(m.group(2))-0xDC00+0x10000),
    s
)
```

Certainly not more straightforward... I also have my doubts as to whether it's actually more efficient!

Comment: Thanks. My input comes from a yaml stream that contained the surrogate code units, and fixing the stream to not contain surrogates does seem to prevent them from showing up in the unicode. So I'll look into fixing the stream.

Comment: What encoding's the YAML? If it's UTF-16 those surrogates *should* be getting converted to single Unicode characters... if it's UTF-8, though, then the producer has made a mistake. (UTF-8-with-surrogates is known as ‘CESU-8’ and shouldn't be used.)

Comment: I'm pretty certain the regex won't be more efficient.

Comment: The yaml itself is a utf-8 encoded str, but the unicode characters in the source data are represented with escape sequences in the yaml. (This is with PyYAML on a python _without_ UCS4.) So `yaml.dump(u'\U0001D10C')` produces this str: `"\uD834\uDD0C"` (len=14).

Comment: That seems to me like a bug in `yaml.dump` (perhaps one that only manifests running on a narrow-Unicode build such as the Windows ones?). The YAML output should also have been `"\U0001D10C"`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the behavior of the CPython interpreter in versions earlier than 3.3 depends on whether it is built with "narrow" or "wide" Unicode support.  So the same code, such as a call to `len`, can have a different result in different builds of the standard interpreter.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934752/platform-specific-unicode-semantics-in-python-2-7) for examples.

The distinction between "narrow" and "wide" is that "narrow" interpreters internally store 16-bit code units (UCS-2), whereas "wide" interpreters internally store 32-bit code units (UCS-4).  Code *points* U+10000 and above (outside the basic-multilingual plane) have a `len` of two on "narrow" interpreters because two UCS-2 code *units* are needed to represent them (using surrogates), and that's what `len` measures.  On "wide" builds only a single UCS-4 code *unit* is required for a non-BMP code *point*, so for those builds `len` is one for such code points.

I have confirmed that the below handles all `unicode` strings whether or not they contain surrogate pairs, and works in CPython 2.7 both narrow and wide builds.  (Arguably, specifying a string like `u'\ud83d\udc4d'` in a wide interpreter reflects an affirmative desire to represent a complete surrogate code *point* as distinct from a partial-character code *unit* and is therefore not automatically an error to be corrected, but I'm ignoring that here.  It's an edge case and normally not a desired use case.)

The `@invoke` trick used below is a way to avoid repeat computation without adding anything to the module's `__dict__`.

```
invoke = lambda f: f()  # trick taken from AJAX frameworks

@invoke
def codepoint_count():
  testlength = len(u'\U00010000')  # pre-compute once
  assert (testlength == 1) or (testlength == 2)
  if testlength == 1:
    def closure(data):  # count function for "wide" interpreter
      u'returns the number of Unicode code points in a unicode string'
      return len(data.encode('UTF-16BE').decode('UTF-16BE'))
  else:
    def is_surrogate(c):
      ordc = ord(c)
      return (ordc >= 55296) and (ordc < 56320)
    def closure(data):  # count function for "narrow" interpreter
      u'returns the number of Unicode code points in a unicode string'
      return len(data) - len(filter(is_surrogate, data))
  return closure

assert codepoint_count(u'hello \U0001f44d') == 7
assert codepoint_count(u'hello \ud83d\udc4d') == 7
```