# platform specific Unicode semantics in Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, unicode, utf-16

Ubuntu 11.10:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:03:08)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = u'\U0001f44d'
>>> len(x)
1
>>> ord(x[0])
128077
```

Windows 7:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x = u'\U0001f44d'
>>> len(x)
2
>>> ord(x[0])
55357
```

My Ubuntu experience is with the default interpreter in the distribution.  For Windows 7 I downloaded and installed the recommended version linked from python.org.  I did not compile either of them myself.

The nature of the difference is clear to me.  (On Ubuntu the string is a sequence of code points; on Windows 7 a sequence of UTF-16 code units.)  My questions are:

- Why am I observing this difference in behavior?  Is it due to how the interpreter is built, or a difference in dependent system libraries?
- Is there any way to configure the behavior of the Windows 7 interpreter to agree with the Ubuntu one, *that I can do within Eclipse PyDev* (my goal)?
- If I have to rebuild, are there any prebuilt Windows 7 interpreters that behave as Ubuntu above from a reliable source?
- Are there any workarounds to this issue besides manually counting surrogates in `unicode` strings on Windows only (blech)?
- Does this justify a bug report?  Is there any chance such a bug report would be addressed in 2.7?

Comment: we talked about Unicode support at Python WM Saturday. Folks said that the 3.3 IO system has been back-ported to Python 2.7. It is midnight here, but someone might respond tomorrow. Is it v urgent?

Comment: I've already started coding a workaround, so no, not urgent.  Disappointing that as late as 3.2 the Unicode string type in Python has wrinkles like this...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Ubuntu, you have a ["wide" Python build](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0261/) where strings are UTF-32/UCS-4.  Unfortunately, this isn't (yet) available for Windows.

> Windows builds will be narrow for a while based on the fact that there
>   have been few requests for wide characters, those requests are mostly
>   from hard-core programmers with the ability to buy their own Python
>   and Windows itself is strongly biased towards 16-bit characters.

Python 3.3 will have [flexible string representation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/), in which you will not need to care about whether Unicode strings use 16-bit or 32-bit code units.

Until then, you can get the code points from a UTF-16 string with

```
def code_points(text):
    utf32 = text.encode('UTF-32LE')
    return struct.unpack('<{}I'.format(len(utf32) // 4), utf32)
```

Answer (score 2):

great question! i fell down this rabbit hole recently myself.

@dan04's answer inspired me to expand it into a `unicode` subclass that provides consistent indexing, slicing, and `len()` on both narrow and wide Python 2 builds:

```
class WideUnicode(unicode):
  """String class with consistent indexing, slicing, len() on both narrow and wide Python."""
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(WideUnicode, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # use UTF-32LE to avoid a byte order marker at the beginning of the string
    self.__utf32le = unicode(self).encode('utf-32le')

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.__utf32le) / 4

  def __getitem__(self, key):
    length = len(self)

    if isinstance(key, int):
      if key >= length:
        raise IndexError()
      key = slice(key, key + 1)

    if key.stop is None:
      key.stop = length

    assert key.step is None

    return WideUnicode(self.__utf32le[key.start * 4:key.stop * 4]
                       .decode('utf-32le'))

  def __getslice__(self, i, j):
    return self.__getitem__(slice(i, j))
```

[open sourced here](https://github.com/snarfed/webutil/blob/ac29df5aaaf7572223e95edc465749a62ed20641/util.py#L1261-L1323), public domain. example usage:

```
text = WideUnicode(obj.text)
for tag in obj.tags:
  text = WideUnicode(text[:start] + tag.text + text[end:])
```

([simplified from this usage.](https://github.com/snarfed/granary/commit/73073aad9fe1b9fd0aaa6688e8cf4bde409d277e#diff-30af2390b148b7d3997f2b2d3928ed96R1175))

thanks @dan04!

Answer (score 1):

I primarily needed to accurately test length.  Hence this function that correctly returns the codepoint length of any `unicode` string, whether the interpreter is narrow or wide built.  If the data uses two surrogate literals instead of a single `\U`-style code point in a wide-built interpreter, the returned codepoint length will account for that as long as the surrogates are used "correctly", i.e. as a narrow-built interpreter would use them.

```
invoke = lambda f: f()  # trick borrowed from Node.js

@invoke
def ulen():
  testlength = len(u'\U00010000')
  assert (testlength == 1) or (testlength == 2)
  if testlength == 1:  # "wide" interpreters
    def closure(data):
      u'returns the number of Unicode code points in a unicode string'
      return len(data.encode('UTF-16BE').decode('UTF-16BE'))
  else:  # "narrow" interpreters
    def filt(c):
      ordc = ord(c)
      return (ordc >= 55296) and (ordc < 56320)
    def closure(data):
      u'returns the number of Unicode code points in a unicode string'
      return len(data) - len(filter(filt, data))
  return closure  # ulen() body is therefore different on narrow vs wide builds
```

Test case, passes on narrow and wide builds:

```
class TestUlen(TestCase):

  def test_ulen(self):
    self.assertEquals(ulen(u'\ud83d\udc4d'), 1)
    self.assertEquals(ulen(u'\U0001F44D'), 1)
```